# Drop file, files property can't read on undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I just have a problem with drop zone for my photos, dataTransfer doesn't work end return as undefault. Please help me and show where I made a mistake. Thank you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#dropbox').on("dragenter dragstart dragend dragleave dragover drag drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
    if(files.length>1) console.log("noooo!");
    else
    {
        console.log("Drop!");
    } 
});
});
```

```css
div {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background:#FFFCCC;
}
```

```html
<html>
    
    <body>
        <div id="dropbox"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `jQuery`, the `event` you have (inside the `drop`) is not the original event, but a jQuery wrapper.

You can use the `e.originalEvent` to get the original event, and there you have the `dataTransfer.files`:

```
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
```

Here is a working example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#dropbox').on("dragenter dragstart dragend dragleave dragover drag drop", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(files);
    if(files.length>1) console.log("noooo!");
    else
    {
      console.log("Drop!");
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  background:#FFFCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropbox"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works.Please describe why I was using jquery events all the time, like "submit" and I not needed ".originalEvent". Maybe jQuery is making ghost event only in some events like "drop"? Explain it please. And what is more you did not used ".originalEvent" in my little cleaner in first handler and it works... and this is same vent 'drop'...